# outWidth and outHeight are 0 in BitmapFactory.Options for image files from FTP server

Tags: android, ftp, decode, ftp-client, bitmapfactory

```
String imageFilePath = "ftp://hostname/dir/imagefilename.jpg";
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options;
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFilePath, options);
int height = options.outHeight;
int width = options.outWidth;
```

But `height` and `width`are always `0`.

I also tried by setting `inJustDecodeBounds = false` but still `decodeFile` method is returning `null`.

When I set `imageFilePath` to a local image file, it worked and again **did not worked** for files from normal `http` websites.

For those who wonder about connection to FTP Server, it is getting connected and authenticated successfully and even I am getting all image files and their names using `FTPClient.listFiles()` and `FTPClient.listNames()`, correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The file path is a locale file, not one hosted on an external file server. You need to download the file yourself, or use a library such as Universal Image Loader or Picasso. Although I don't know how well (if) they work with ftp